# Different Weighted Linear Regression Results for R and Python, Bug or Just Different Interpretation?

Tags: python, r, statsmodels

I was learning weight linear regression and comparing the results of R and Python.  Then I noticed that the results are quite different from these two, particularly for F-stats.  There are two test cases.  I will ask my questions after presenting the two cases.

**Case 1: Weighted Linear Regression with Full Rank Matrix**

This is a super simple dataset.  So the coefficients are basically going to be the same regardless which linear regression algorithm one is going to use.

Python:

```py
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
x = np.asarray ((18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29), dtype = float)
A = sm.add_constant (x)
y = np.asarray ((76.1, 77.0, 78.1, 78.2, 78.8, 79.7, 79.9, 81.1, 81.2, 81.8, 82.8, 83.5), dtype = float)
wt = np.asarray ((0.21, 0.15, 0.11, 0.0, -0.0, 0.11, 0.12, 0.15, 0.1, 0.2, 0.15, 0.4 ), dtype = float)
model = sm.WLS (y, A, weights = wt).fit ()
print (model.summary ())
```

Output:

```
                            WLS Regression Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.992
Model:                            WLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.991
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     1241.
Date:                Fri, 19 May 2023   Prob (F-statistic):           8.07e-12
Time:                        11:55:00   Log-Likelihood:                   -inf
No. Observations:                  12   AIC:                               inf
Df Residuals:                      10   BIC:                               inf
Df Model:                           1
Covariance Type:            nonrobust
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const         64.6927      0.456    141.786      0.000      63.676      65.709
x1             0.6452      0.018     35.223      0.000       0.604       0.686
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        0.164   Durbin-Watson:                   2.140
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.921   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.363
Skew:                           0.120   Prob(JB):                        0.834
Kurtosis:                       2.183   Cond. No.                         155.
==============================================================================
```

R:

```r
A <- matrix(c( 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 ), nrow = 12, ncol = 1)
y <- c(76.1, 77.0, 78.1, 78.2, 78.8, 79.7, 79.9, 81.1, 81.2, 81.8, 82.8, 83.5)
wt <- c(0.21, 0.15, 0.11, 0.0, -0.0, 0.11, 0.12, 0.15, 0.1, 0.2, 0.15, 0.4 )
model <- lm (y ~ A, weights=wt)
summary (model)
```

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ A, weights = wt)

Weighted Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.140456 -0.087469  0.007881  0.056603  0.166686 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 64.69272    0.51013   126.8 1.67e-14 ***
A            0.64524    0.02048    31.5 1.12e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1071 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.992,     Adjusted R-squared:  0.991 
F-statistic: 992.5 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 1.121e-09
```

There are several differences.

1. Standard error and t-stats for individual coefficients are different.
2. F-stats is different.

**Case 2: Weighted Linear Regression with Rank-deficient Matrix**

Python:

```py
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
x1 = np.asarray ([ -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], dtype=float)
x2 = np.asarray ([ 4, 1, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25 ], dtype=float)
x3 = np.asarray ([ 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 12 ], dtype=float)
y = np.asarray ([ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ], dtype=float)
A = np.asarray ([ np.ones (7, dtype=float), x1, x2, x2, x3 ]).T
wt = np.asarray ((0.11, 0.12, 0.0, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.15), dtype = float)
model = sm.WLS (y, A, weights = wt).fit ()
print (model.summary ())
```

Output:

```
                            WLS Regression Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.998
Model:                            WLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.996
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     532.9
Date:                Fri, 19 May 2023   Prob (F-statistic):           0.000138
Time:                        11:53:14   Log-Likelihood:                   -inf
No. Observations:                   7   AIC:                               inf
Df Residuals:                       3   BIC:                               inf
Df Model:                           3
Covariance Type:            nonrobust
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          3.0725      0.378      8.125      0.004       1.869       4.276
x1             0.6204      0.111      5.597      0.011       0.268       0.973
x2             0.0141      0.006      2.397      0.096      -0.005       0.033
x3             0.0141      0.006      2.397      0.096      -0.005       0.033
x4             0.0885      0.077      1.152      0.333      -0.156       0.333
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                          nan   Durbin-Watson:                   2.656
Prob(Omnibus):                    nan   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.452
Skew:                           0.542   Prob(JB):                        0.798
Kurtosis:                       2.389   Cond. No.                     1.46e+17
==============================================================================
```

R:

```r
A <- matrix(c( -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
              4, 1, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25,
              4, 1, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25,
              2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 12), nrow = 7, ncol = 4)
y <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
wt <- c(0.11, 0.12, 0.0, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.15)
model <- lm (y ~ A, weights=wt)
summary (model)
```

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ A, weights = wt)

Weighted Residuals:
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7 
-0.040387  0.057390  0.000000 -0.017136  0.005993 -0.027315  0.022026 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  3.07250    0.46316   6.634   0.0220 *
A1           0.62040    0.13577   4.570   0.0447 *
A2           0.02827    0.01445   1.957   0.1895  
A3                NA         NA      NA       NA  
A4           0.08849    0.09404   0.941   0.4461  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.05695 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9981,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9953 
F-statistic: 355.2 on 3 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.002808
```

It appears that R uses QR Householder to compute the linear model, while Python uses pseudoinverse.  So the coefficients for A2 and A3 are different.

Again, notice f-statistics is different.

**Questions**

Question 1. Why is the difference in standard error and t-value in case 1?

The weighted matrix A2 is

```
array([[ 0.45825757,  8.24863625],
       [ 0.38729833,  7.35866836],
       [ 0.33166248,  6.63324958],
       [ 0.33166248,  7.62823702],
       [ 0.34641016,  8.31384388],
       [ 0.38729833,  9.68245837],
       [ 0.31622777,  8.22192192],
       [ 0.4472136 , 12.07476708],
       [ 0.38729833, 10.84435337],
       [ 0.63245553, 18.34121043]])
```

np.linalg.inv (A2.T @ A2) is

```
array([[22.68020619, -0.89869228],
       [-0.89869228,  0.03655843]])
```

np.diag (np.linalg.inv (A2.T @ A2))

```
array([22.68020619,  0.03655843])
```

Also, RSS is 0.091790911146517828

R's standard error computation appears to be the following.

```py
rse = np.sqrt (rss / residualDF)        # (residualDF is 8 here)
standardError = rse * np.sqrt (np.diag (np.linalg.inv (A2.T @ A2)))
```

So the result is

```
array([0.51012704, 0.02048088])
```

However, I don't get how Python does its calculation.  Is it just a different formula?  Or are the standard errors being referred to the same thing?

Question 2. Why is the difference in F-stats?

It appears to me that the degrees of freedom used in computations are just different.  Who is right?

Both R and python computed RSS as 0.091790911146517828, ESS as 11.38803026532697

For R, it appears to be using the following formula

```
    (ess / DF_ess) / (rss / DF_rss)
```

DF_rss = 1, DF_ess is 8.  So the result is 992.5192046214006

However, it appears that Python uses a different formula.

```py
    return self.mse_model/self.mse_resid
```

Here, mse_model value is the same as ess value.  mse_resid is computed as self.ssr/self.df_resid

Here is the problem: df_resid is 10 here.  As the result, the computed fvalue is 1240.649.

The case 2 F-stats value is different for a similar reason.

Which one is right?  Or are they referring to the same thing?

Comment: In Case 1, it seems like R and Python handle weights which are negative and zero differently. R removes the example, and Python doesn't. If you remove the fourth and fifth elements from x, y, and wt, then Python gets the same standard errors and F score that R does. Not sure it makes much sense to use zero or negative weights - it implies that you're either indifferent to how well it fits or you want the model to get it as wrong as possible.

Comment: Weight cannot be negative due to the simple fact that you have to calculate sqrt (weight).  I deliberately put -0.0 in there just for fun since it is just 0.  Weight can be 0, but they will not be counted in LeastSquare equation (either using pseudoinverse or QR), this is both the case for R and Python.  Notice that Python's coefficients is computed on matrix A2 (which eliminates 0 weight entries) is as given, just using pseudoinverse.

Comment: The two entries with 0 weight affect the degrees of freedom of the model, which affects the standard error calculation. I'm not sure I understand the objection around A2 - I don't understand how that was calculated. Are you saying that statsmodels calculates A2 somewhere internally?

Comment: Let me double check.

Comment: After some calculation checks, A2 is not important.  However, looks like Python did standard error / t-stats calculations without 0 weight entries removed in terms of degrees of freedoms (residual DF, unexplained DF and rsq).  Then the question becomes, should we count 0 weight entries in various stats calculations?

Comment: I still have some calculations not lining up for case 2.

Comment: Thank you Nick.  After a number of tests, I finally got very consistent results.  The only difference between Python and R is that R is removing 0 weights in stats (degrees of freedom) calculations.

Comment: Can you explain why a zero weight should have a degree of freedom?

Comment: Statsmodels does not special case zero weights which implies that the results are continuous when weights approach zero. (weights in WLS are interpreted as variance weights with continuity as var_i goes to inf)